# Spring Boot 2 upgrade caused HATEOAS href link vs _links issue and now request to that link kicks back out to login screen

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-hateoas

We upgraded our apps from spring boot 1.5.19 to 2.2.7.  We have a UI app and an API services app.    The API app returns responses with a links object like below:

```
"links": [],
"links": [
  {
    "rel": "all",
     "href": "https://server:port/foo/bar{?page,size}"
  }
 ]
```

Previous the response contained a single "_links" object but now it contains two "links" and one is empty.  We changed the dashboard to grab the "links" object that actually contains data.  However, now whenever we click on any of the links that translate to the href in the "links" object we get kicked back out to the login screen even though we already logged in.  I set logging to debug for spring and there things that seem odd but may be normal:

```
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

and

```
SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
```

but I dont really have any idea where to go with them. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this:

```
@Bean
ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
}
```